# jquery set all checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am using jquery 1.11.1 and this is my code:

```
$("#rowchkall").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $("input:checkbox[class=rowchk]").each(function() {
            alert("set checked");
            $(this).attr('checked', "checked");
        });
    }else{
        $("input:checkbox[class=rowchk]").each(function() {
            $(this).attr('checked', false);
        });
    } 
});
```

When I first click on `#rowchkall`, all the checkbox is set to checked. When I click it again, all checkbox is unchecked.

When I click it again, alert box still appear but none of the checkbox will be checked. Why is it only work for first time only? How can I fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$(this).prop('checked', true); //true to check else false uncheck
```

Your code can be simplified as

```
$("#rowchkall").change(function () {
    $("input:checkbox.rowchk").prop('checked',this.checked);
});
```

A Good Read [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Answer (score 6):

Try to use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$("#rowchkall").change(function(){
  $("input:checkbox[class=rowchk]").prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

And you don't need to `iterate` over all the elements to change its property.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#rowchkall").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $("input.rowchk[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
            alert("set checked");
            $(this).attr('checked',true);
        });
    }else{
        $("input.rowchk[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
            $(this).attr('checked', false);
        });
    } 
});
```