# Set all checkbox in Kendo Dropdowntree checked when load the page

Tags: checkbox, kendo-ui, treeview, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-treeview

I want to create kendo dropdowntree where when i load the page, all the checkbox is checked. Here is my code.

```
    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownTree()
                          .AutoWidth(true)
                          .Name("dropdowntree")
                          .DataTextField("Name")
                          .DataValueField("Id")
                          .CheckAll(true)
                          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%" })
                          .Events(events => events.Change("onChange"))
                          .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
                          .AutoClose(false)
                          .Checkboxes(checkboxes => checkboxes
                              .Name("checkedFiles")
                              .CheckChildren(true)
                          )
                          .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                            .Read(read => read
                            .Action("GetName", "CheckBox")
                        )
                        )
    )
```

I already doing some research and try the solution, but none if them work. For example, what i have try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#dropdowntree input.k-checkbox").prop("checked", true);
})
```

This one also not work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dropdowntree").attr('checked', 'checked');
})
```

This one is work, but i need to set the value. What i need is it checked all by default, no need to set the value.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 var dropdowntree = $("#dropdowntree").data("kendoDropDownTree");
 dropdowntree.value(["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]); 
 })
```

Other than all of these, i also try the solution in this link [jquery set all checkbox checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24774029/jquery-set-all-checkbox-checked) and others solution. But still not work. I really need some advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found the answer if there is someone need it.

First in controller i get all of the list for id, then i change the list into string in json.

CONTROLLER CODE:

```
    public IActionResult CheckBoxDB()
    {
        List<string> parts = new List<string>();
        GetId(parts);
        ViewBag.All = parts;
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parts);
        ViewBag.change = json;
        return View();
    }

    private void GetId(List<string> parts)
    {
        List<DdlcheckBox> ddlcheckBoxes = new List<DdlcheckBox>();
        ddlcheckBoxes = _context.DdlcheckBox.ToList();
        foreach (var data in ddlcheckBoxes)
        {
            string id = data.Id.ToString();
            parts.Add(id);
        }
    }
```

Then, in the Views, i get the ViewBag value at the script.

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dropdowntree = $("#dropdowntree").data("kendoDropDownTree");
    dropdowntree.value('@ViewBag.change');
});
 </script>
```

Thank you.